# Uploading to OpenStreetMap with JOSM?

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, josm

I uploaded a shapefile from JOSM to OpenStreetMap a week ago and I still cannot see  any changes on osm map. Yet when I visit my profile I see clearly that the shape was uploaded.

Do you know how much time the approval takes?

Or maybe what could be wrong with the shape?

Comment: Please tell us your changeset ID or the area in question or your user name. Also, typically uploading a shapefile to OSM is *not* recommended. See the [import guidelines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines). Also, this question is better asked at http://help.openstreetmap.org/

Comment: my username is "zakigates". The area in question is "Parc national d'Al Hoceima

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added [way 637458054](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/637458054). See the [history of this way](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/637458054/history). The way has been deleted by user johnparis with the comment "partial duplicate".

Your way doesn't have useful [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) except for the name. It has some uppercase tags `Id`, `Type` and also `sup` which don't correspond do any established tagging scheme. What are they for?

What exactly is this object supposed to be? If you want to add a boundary then please read the documentation about the [boundary=administrative](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dadministrative) tag.

The same applies to you newer ways [638982276](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/638982276) and [638972780](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/638972780) which also lack any meaningful tags.

There is no "approval". You always edit the OSM database right away.

- Please stop what you are doing right now. You are doing it wrong. Sorry for the harsh wording.
- Don't add meaningless, random tags. Keep to established and documented tags (there are few cases where this rule doesn't apply).
- Don't just import random shapefiles to OSM. Read the [import guidelines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Import/Guidelines) before and get into contact with the community *before* importing! Also make sure you use valid sources and don't overwrite/duplicate existing data in OSM.

Next time please use one of the [OSM contact channels](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Contact_channels) such as http://help.openstreetmap.org/, mailing lists, forums or IRC channels. https://gis.stackexchange.com is the wrong place for these questions.

Comment: You are welcome. If you think your data is useful for OSM and is currently still missing then please get into contact with the community. OSM is always open for new contributions :)